# C# WindowsForms How to switch drag and drop operation

Tags: c#, forms, label, drag

I've a question about drag and drop in C#/Windows Forms. 
I've 2 labels. "labelPos25" and "labelPos32A". I want to switch each other via drag and drop. So the text of labelPos25 is the text of labelPos32A and text of labelPos32A is text of labelPos25 after the drag and drop.

I've created these functions to move labelPos25 on labelPos32A:

```
private void LabelPos32A_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void LabelPos32A_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var ob = sender as Label;
            ob.Text = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

        }

        private void LabelPos25_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var ob = sender as Label;
            DoDragDrop(ob.Text, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
```

How can I force a switch of the label texts instead of a moving? Is there any way?

Comment: Its up to you what happens when something is dragged and dropped, if you want to swap them you can do just that

Comment: Yeah but I want to know how I could start a DragDropEffects.Move inside LabelPos32A_DragDrop for labelPos25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a different overload for both `GetData` and `GetDataPresent`. Instead of `string` you can use `Type` as parameter and then you can access not just the `Text` but the whole `Label`..:

```
private void LabelPos32A_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Label))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void LabelPos32A_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var ob2 = sender as Label;
    var ob1 = (Label)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Label));
    string s2 = ob2.Text;
    ob2.Text = ob1.Text;
    ob1.Text = s2;
}

private void LabelPos25_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var ob = sender as Label;
    DoDragDrop(ob, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

If you want to you could also switch the two `Labels` themselves, i.e. not just `Text` but instead the `Location`..:

```
   Point p2 = ob2.Location;
   ob2.Location = ob1.Location;
   ob1.Location = p2;
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!!